# How we can check everyday in S3 Bucket that's json file has new data inserted or not. what's the best way to get only new data which inserted.?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to do a code in python to retrieve new data which inserted in AWS S3 bucket i.e in JSON file. I need to run code everyday to check is their any new data has inserted or not in JSON file, if inserted then i need to retrieve only new data from AWS S3 bucket.

Comment: What are you looking to do with this data? Write it to a DB, or something else?

Comment: when any data will be added then i need to send email regarding this.

Comment: please vote my question to help.

Comment: So in effect, when there is any object created in the bucket, you need to trigger an email to a address? A solution to this is to use a Lambda that triggers on object creation, that triggers an email through SNS, however there are many other unknowns for me, so I cannot provide you with a detailed solution. Put some code together yourself based on the above suggestion though, and I'm happy to help.

Comment: sending email that i'll take care through lambda but i need to know how i can retrieve data from json file when any new data will insert. I need to check everyday if any data has been inserted.

Comment: You do not need to check, as S3 supports triggering lambda's on object creation/update, and can retrieve contents of the json file through the lambda function.

Comment: i know that with the help of Boto3 i can retrieve data through lambda but i need to check everytime in json file that is their any new data is their not as compare to latest file with yesterday json file. If any difference will be happen yesterday file and today file then i will need to send that data through email by sing AWS SES.